# Outputting appeded list of items into a file

Tags: python

I have a variable,all=[], which stores an appended list of items as follows:

```
qwe 1qw78 12 qqq ss7 shhs bs77 sghs 7shsb qwe 1qw78 12 qqq ss7 shhs bs77 sghs 7shsb
```

I tried to ouput the items in a tab-delimited format as 3 columns into a file as follows:

output wanted:

```
qwe 1qw78 12
qqq ss7 shhs
bs77 sghs 7shsb
```

I was not exactly sure how to do this, but my attempt is below:

```
all=[]
with open("file.txt", "r") as input, open("output.txt","w") as outfile:
    for line in input:
    line=line.rstrip()
    all.append(line)        
    for i,item in enumerate(all):
        for i in range(3):
        outfile.write("%s \t" %all)
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify which are the list items, groups of characters or individual characters?

Comment: Can you check the indentation in the sample code please. It doesn't make sense as it stands.

Comment: Also can you a post a sample of your input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all is a list the following will work, replacing all with lst:

```
grouped = (lst[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(lst),3))

with open("output.txt","w") as f:
    for tup in grouped:
        f.write("\t".join(tup)+"\n")
```

If each line is as in your question just split each line:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as input, open("output.txt","w") as outfile:
for line in input:
    line = line.rstrip().split()
    grouped = (lst[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(lst),3))
    for tup in grouped:            
        outfile.write("\t".join(tup)+"\n")
```

If you  have a word on each line then modulo and enumerate will do what you want:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as inp, open("output.txt","w") as outfile:
    for ind, line in enumerate(inp,1):
        if ind % 3 == 0:
            outfile.write(line.rstrip()+"\n")
        else:
            outfile.write(line.rstrip() + "\t")
```

Comment: @Pradraic, thanks for your wonderful solutions and time. I found them very useful. Much appreciated!